# Any way to find the solutions of contest problems made by contestants in the exam?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, contest-math

Whenever I went through any *Wikipedia article* or any specific analysis or documentary on a problem of **IMO**, **Putnam** or questions from different *National level Olympiad programs*, I used to find written that "this user find the solution in this way or that way", "which was very clever or short" but I don't find them anywhere.

> So do anybody know such resources or where I  can find it?

Comment: [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c13_contests)has a collection  contest problems and is solved by many users.You can check it out